# MMDrawerController and constraints

Tags: ios, swift, mmdrawercontroller

I am using MMDrawerController to show menu in my app - i use one of my ViewControllers for this.

I have problem some problems with constraints.
When my menu VC is loaded for the first time - it show all elements in left corner and after second they are placed normally.

So at first time constraints are working only after all UI elements had loaded. What can i do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this problem too. I found a (dirty) workaround which consists in calling

```
[drawerController bouncePreviewForDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft distance:0.1f completion:nil]; // Hack for layout bug in menu
```

to force the drawer to process its layout.

Comment: Are you having this problem when you open menu by sliding or by toggle method?
how it can be done in swift?

Comment: I observed that the layout was not correctly rendered before the 2nd opening of the drawer, no matter what method I use. I'm not familiar with swift, but I guess it should work like any other method call.

Comment: In Swift it looks like 
centerContainer?.bouncePreviewForDrawerSide(.Left, distance: 0.5, completion: nil)

Comment: I too ran into this problem when using MGSlidingTableCell in my Left Side View. This definitely fixed it. I admit, it is dirty, but... unless there is another way to force the controller to process its layout this is harmless.